# Probability of choosing red $\geq 11$ times out of $21$ and probability of choosing red $= 3/4$?

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

As per the title of the question, I'm interested in finding out how exactly to calculate the probability of choosing, let's say, a red ball out of a bag of balls $\geq 11$ times out of $21$ random, independent trials, and the probability of choosing red is $3/4$ for a single trial?

I understand that in "greater than" scenarios, it's equivalent to the probability of choosing a red ball exactly 11 times + 12 times + ... + 21 times, and for that you use the combination formula (or binomial theorem?), but I'm mostly confused on where exactly the $3/4$ factors into the entire calculation?

Comment: In the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) the $\frac{3}{4}$ will play the role of $p$.  Letting $X$ be the random variable counting the number of successes, the probability that exactly $k$ occurrences out of $n$ will be "successes" where success has probability $p$ will be $Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can calculate the probability of choosing *exactly* 11 red balls out of 21:

First, there are $21 \choose 11$ possible ways of getting 11 red balls out of 21.  For example, you can start with picking 11 red balls, followed by 10 non-red balls, or first pck 10 non-red balls, and then 11 red balls, or start with a red ball, and alternate with non-red balls, or ...  Again, the number of possible ways or sequences here is $21 \choose 11$

Now, if we focus on a specific sequence:

11 times you need to pick a red ball: $\big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{11}$ (here is where the $\frac{3}{4}$ comes in)

and 10 times you need to pick a non-red ball: $\big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^{10}$ (the $\frac{1}{4}$ is of course the probability of getting a non-red ball on a single draw, which is $1- \frac{3}{4}$, so this is where the $\frac{3}{4}$ comes in again)

So, a specific sequence occurs with a chance of $\big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{11} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^{10}$

But since you have $21 \choose 11$ of such possible sequences, (all of which are mutually exclusive), we can add up their probabilities, i.e. we get a probability of:

$\big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{11} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^{10} \cdot {21 \choose 11}$

of getting *exactly* 11 red balls

OK, so now you add to this the probability of getting exactly 12 red balls, 13, etc.

P.s. It's too bad the probability of getting a red ball on a single draw is not $\frac{1}{2}$, for then the answer would be very easy ... do you see what it would be and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three methods of computing such binomial probabilities: (1) Using the formula for the PDF of the relevant binomial distribution, (2) using a normal approximation to binomial, (3) computing exact binomial probabilities using mathematical or statistical software.

You have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 21, p=3/4)$ and you seek 
$$P(X \ge 11) = P(X > 10) = 1 - P(X \le 10).$$

(1) You are correct that you need to find $P(X = 11) + P(X=12) + \cdots + P(X=21).$ @Bram28 has discussed this in some detail (+1).

(2) This binomial distribution has $E(X) = \mu = np = 21(3/4) = 15.75$ and
$SD(X) = \sigma = \sqrt{21(3/4)(1/4)} =  1.9843.$ The normal distribution
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 15.75, \sigma = 1.9843)$ provides a
reasonably good approximation.

$$P(X \ge 10.5) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{10.5-15.75}{1.9843}\right) \approx P(Z > -2.6458),$$
where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution. You can evaluate this
probability using printed normal tables, but you will need to use -2.65
instead of -2.6458. The answer is about  0.9959 or 0.9960, depending on 
the table you use and how much rounding you do.

The figure below shows bars for binomial probabilities and the density curve of the 'best fitting' normal. You want the probability to the right of the vertical broken line.

[image]

*Note:* In view of the figure, you might come very close in (1) by using the binomial PDF to find
$P(X = 8) + P(X = 9) + P(X = 10)$ and subtracting the total from $1$, because there seems to be almost no binomial probability less than 8.

(3) You can use a statistical calculator or software to find the exact
probability. For example, using R statistical software (in which `pbinom` is
the binomial CDF), we have the result 0.9936.

```
1 - pbinom(10, 21, 3/4)  
## 0.9935773
```